# Default folder setup for a large project

Tags: c++, directory

As I am trying to learn C++ I have begun on a larger project where I try to use classes in order to avoid a messy `main.cpp` file. This means that I am creating more `.cpp` files which I have placed in the same folder as the `main.cpp` file. This has resulted in a messy directory aswell so I tried managing my files by adding folders following the two links:

- **Link1:** https://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/
- **Link2:** https://mariuszbartosik.com/directory-structure-for-a-c-project/

My questions are the following:

- Does a standard for creating C++ projects exist that is used in a
  workplace or is every project subjectively created?
- If a standard does not exist are there any bad practises that should
  be avoided when creating a folder structure?
- Can I create a folder structure where I put all the header `(.h)`
  files in one directory and all the source files `(.cpp)` in another
  directory such as `C:\headers\header.h` and `C:\source\main.cpp` to
  in my    include use a `#define HEADER "/path to header"` and then
  somehow    `#include HEADER "aheader.h"` which would mean that I dont
  need to    everytime when including a header write the path to the
  header    directory and instead write HEADER before the include?

Example:

Instead of:

```
#include "c:\headers\header.h"
#include "c:\headers\anotherheader.h"
```

Use:

```
#define HEADER "c:\headers\"
#include HEADER "header.h"
#include HEADER "anotherheader.h"
```

I am asking this because I would like to avoid all bad practise when learning to code in C++ so I wont do mistakes later on. Since I have no work experience I dont know if the guides I found online are good ones in practise.

My current structure:

[image: Current structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a standard for creating C++ projects exist that is used in a
>   workplace or is every project subjectively created?

No, you can find different structures across different projects.

> If a standard does not exist are there any bad practices that should
>   be avoided when creating a folder structure?

You should:

- Put your compiled files in a different folder (bin maybe).
- Organize your project in different logical modules placed in different folders.
- Use the root folder for not-code files (makefile, gitignore, etc...).
- Use lowercase names only to avoid silly mistakes.

You should not:

- Use absolute paths.

> Can I create a folder structure where I put all the header (.h)
>   files in one directory and all the source files (.cpp) in another directory such as C:\headers\header.h and C:\source\main.cpp to in my include use a #define HEADER "/path to header" and then somehow  #include HEADER "aheader.h" which would mean that I dont need to everytime when including a header write the path to the header directory and instead write HEADER before the include?

No, that's really bad.

I don't like use different folders for source/header files, but if you want to. You can work around using include paths (-l flag).

So you would use:

```
#include <header.h>
#include <anotherheader.h>
```

That works because you are including the folder on compile time:

```
g++ -l "../headers" enemy.cpp
```

Any sensible IDE will do this for you. Or you could do it on your makefile, whatever suits you.

Comment: So using one folder for all source and headers is the way to go? What about if you would like to use modules or something similar, wouldnt it be good to use the structure im currently using where I have a folder for every source and h file?

Comment: @darclander any module should have his own folder. My point is, .cpp and .h files should be at the same folder.

Comment: did you see the image I included in the question? I have one folder for every module where test.cpp is in same folder as test.h. Is that a good way to proceed? @amchacon

Comment: @darclander no, you are almost using a folder for every folder. That's too far.

Comment: Instead, you should group them in general concepts. Like: "engine", "database", etc...

Comment: Hmm so lets say I make a folder for a player and have inventory and classes in that one aswell but I also want the enemy to have an inventory. Do I put inventory in both folders then or should I use a separete one for that? @amchacon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194989/discussion-between-darclander-and-amchacon).